# repeating jquery function many times

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I need to improve my jquery code where I repeat my function 6 times!!! 
is there away to do a loop to shorten the code ?

```js
(function( jQuery ){
    jQuery.fn.vesta = function(imgN){
        var imgPath = "http://localhost:8080/mhost/media/magentohost/vesta/vesta"
        var currImg = imgPath + imgN + ".png";
        var targetImg = jQuery('.img-browser img');
        jQuery('.img-browser img').attr('src', currImg);
    }
})( jQuery );

jQuery('.vesta1').on('click', function (e) {
    jQuery('.vesta1').vesta(1);
});
jQuery('.vesta2').on('click', function (e) {
    jQuery('.vesta2').vesta(2);
});
jQuery('.vesta3').on('click', function (e) {
    jQuery('.vesta3').vesta(3);
});
jQuery('.vesta4').on('click', function (e) {
    jQuery('.vesta4').vesta(4);
});
jQuery('.vesta5').on('click', function (e) {
    jQuery('.vesta5').vesta(5);
});
jQuery('.vesta6').on('click', function (e) {
    jQuery('.vesta6').vesta(6);
});
```

Comment: Can you also post your HTML so we can see how its structured.

Comment: Was that code snippet meant to do something? What's your HTML?

Answer (score 4):

You can DRY this up by using a common class, and a `data` attribute to specify the parameter to send to your `vesta` function:

```
<div class="vesta" data-vesta="1">1</div>
<div class="vesta" data-vesta="2">2</div>
<div class="vesta" data-vesta="3">2</div>
```

Then there is no need to loop at all:

```
$('.vesta').on('click', function (e) {
    $(this).vesta($(this).data('vesta'));
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Just put it into a `for` loop, and take advantage of the dynamic nature of JavaScript:

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 6; i++) {
    $('.vesta' + i).on('click', (function (index) {
        return function (e) {
            $('.vesta' + index).vesta(index);
        };
    })(i));
}
```

Comment: [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Comment: this code won't work.  `i` will be bound to the wrong value when the click handler is invoked.

Comment: Updated my answer with a closure

Answer (score 2):

Use a common class and a data attribute

```
jQuery('.vesta').on('click', function (e) {
    var elem = $(this);
    elem.vesta(elem.data("ind"));
});
```

and the HTML

```
<div class="vesta vesta1" data-ind="1">
```

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you need the `this` reference along with some hack kind of thing

```
$('[class*=vespa]').on('click', function(e){
    $(this).vesta(+(this.className.match(/vespa(\d+)/)[1]))
});
```

Here, we capture elements which have a class that matches at least `vespa` and then we use some bit of regex to match the digits after `vespa` and `+` unary operator changes the `String` version of numbers into *actual* numbers.

Answer (score 1):

It would be quite easy if you can alter the structure of the HTML.
You would give all elements the same class, say `vesta`. But you also give them an attribute, say `data-number`. For example, like this:

```
<div class="vesta" data-number="4"></div>
```

Then, your jQuery code would be as simple as:

```
$(document).on({
    click: function() {
        var $this = $(this),
            number = +$this.data('number');

        $this.vesta(number);
    }
}, '.vesta');
```

Comment: @epascarello thanks, corrected - I forgot how I wanted to call the `on` method while typing my answer! :)

Answer (score -1):

Edit:
I was a bit lazy with explaining the code snippet that I have provided an hour ago, but I am modifying my post now in response to the comments.

This code snippet will allow you to apply listeners from '.vesta1' elements to '.vestaN'

[@Variable]

NumberOfClasses - is the positive integer after 'vesta'. Eg: vesta1 ,vesta2, vesta100 ... etc

```
var NumberOfClasses=6;
for(var i=1;i<=NumberOfClasses;i++){
    var className = '.vesta'+(i+1);
    jQuery(className ).on('click', function (e) {
        $(this).vesta(i);
    });
}
```

Comment: You should really explain your answer a little.

Comment: It's just a replacement for those 6 onclick listeners written by the thread opener

Comment: Please explain this in the **answer**, not in a comment.

Comment: Why use `i=0;i<limit` and `i+1` instead of `i=1;i<=limit` and `i`?

Comment: It also has the same mistake my solution had.